# @XmlAttribute appears as @XmlElement

Tags: java, xml, soap

On my webservice I define a variable as `@XmlAttribute`:

```
@XmlAttribute
protected String domain;
```

But when I make a query via SoapUi, it appears as an XML element:

```
<ns:domain>domain</ns:domain>
```

I can't find any mistake in my code..

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reimplemented the project with the [Axis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Axis) 2 code generator. Now it works.

I don't know what was the mistake..

Answer (score 1):

You show the annotation on the field, but JAXB uses property (getter/setter method) access by default. Have you changed JAXB's default access? Try putting the annotation on the getter method instead.

**Edit:** Since you seem to be having trouble, here's an executable example:

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import java.io.StringWriter;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Foo foo = new Foo("my attribute value", "my element value");
    Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class).createMarshaller();
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    marshaller.marshal(foo, stringWriter);
    System.out.println(stringWriter);
}

@XmlRootElement
static class Foo {
    private String anAttribute;
    private String anElement;

    Foo() {}

    public Foo(String anAttribute, String anElement) {
        this.anAttribute = anAttribute;
        this.anElement = anElement;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getAnAttribute() { return anAttribute; }
    @XmlElement
    public String getAnElement() { return anElement; }
}
```

Output (formatted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<foo anAttribute="my attribute value">
    <anElement>my element value</anElement>
</foo>
```

Comment: I tried it like this:    @XmlAttribute
    public String getDomain() {
        return domain;
    }   doesn't work